# How do I perform an action when an Android Notification is complete?

Tags: android, notifications

I have a service that starts a broadcastReceiver to listen for an SMS. If the specific SMS is received it sets the notification volume to maximum and fires a notification.

How can I return the volume to the previous setting AFTER the notification has completed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this directly, and as a workaround you can try to get the current notification sound's length, wait for that specific period, and then change the volume. I don't think it's very reliable though ...

Answer (score 1):

There is no notion of a "notification has completed".

If you mean "when the sound for my notification has completed", you know how long the sound is. Use `AlarmManager` to schedule an alarm to get notified after that amount of time has elapsed (perhaps plus a second or two, to be sure), and then change the volume back when that alarm goes off.

Or, better yet, don't mess with the volume in the first place.

Comment: "Or, better yet, don't mess with the volume in the first place." words of wisdom!